# Pandas parse csv column from dict into table

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My csv file:

```
FILE_INFO,                                                                                                                                        CATEGORY,    AREA,              BOX,                     NAME
"{'id': 1, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic1.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",PRODUCT,2247.8981,"[2283.54, 934.13, 27.37, 82.13]","{'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False}"
"{'id': 2, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic2.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",PRODUCT,2450.7795,"[2239.91, 1284.21, 33.15, 73.93]","{'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False}"
"{'id': 3, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic3.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",INDUSTRIAL litter,2548.956,"[2316.07, 301.5, 68.3, 37.32]","{'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False}"
"{'id': 4, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic4.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",INDUSTRIAL litter,1465.0172,"[3394.37, 1083.97, 26.99, 54.28]","{'subcategory': 'PAPER', 'occluded': False}"
```

How can I parse **FILE_INFO** column and get just **file_name** table without any other information. Same with **NAME** column and get only **subcategory** from it.
Others tables are good.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the values in a for loop and use JSON to extract the data you need.

So in a for loop you would do something like this:

```
import json

for row in rows:
    json.loads(row.replace("\'", "\""))['file_name']
```

Comment: its not json its csv

Answer (score 0):

The main workaround is that the JSON column is not well formed to get into it with `json.loads()`

- replace single quotes with double quotes to make it well formed
- `json.loads()` to convert from string to `dict`
- `apply(pd.Series)` to expand dict to columns

Now you have simple to navigate dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''FILE_INFO,                                                                                                                                        CATEGORY,    AREA,              BOX,                     NAME
"{'id': 1, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic1.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",PRODUCT,2247.8981,"[2283.54, 934.13, 27.37, 82.13]","{'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False}"
"{'id': 2, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic2.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",PRODUCT,2450.7795,"[2239.91, 1284.21, 33.15, 73.93]","{'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False}"
"{'id': 3, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic3.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",INDUSTRIAL litter,2548.956,"[2316.07, 301.5, 68.3, 37.32]","{'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False}"
"{'id': 4, 'width': 4032, 'height': 3024, 'file_name': 'pic4.jpeg', 'license': 0, 'flickr_url': '', 'coco_url': '', 'date_captured': 0}",INDUSTRIAL litter,1465.0172,"[3394.37, 1083.97, 26.99, 54.28]","{'subcategory': 'PAPER', 'occluded': False}"'''))

df = df.drop(columns="FILE_INFO").join(df.FILE_INFO.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x.replace("'","\""))).apply(pd.Series))
```

|  | CATEGORY | AREA | BOX | NAME | id | width | height | file_name | license | flickr_url | coco_url | date_captured |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PRODUCT | 2247.9 | [2283.54, 934.13, 27.37, 82.13] | {'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False} | 1 | 4032 | 3024 | pic1.jpeg | 0 |  |  | 0 |
| 1 | PRODUCT | 2450.78 | [2239.91, 1284.21, 33.15, 73.93] | {'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False} | 2 | 4032 | 3024 | pic2.jpeg | 0 |  |  | 0 |
| 2 | INDUSTRIAL litter | 2548.96 | [2316.07, 301.5, 68.3, 37.32] | {'subcategory': 'BOTTLE', 'occluded': False} | 3 | 4032 | 3024 | pic3.jpeg | 0 |  |  | 0 |
| 3 | INDUSTRIAL litter | 1465.02 | [3394.37, 1083.97, 26.99, 54.28] | {'subcategory': 'PAPER', 'occluded': False} | 4 | 4032 | 3024 | pic4.jpeg | 0 |  |  | 0 |

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("my.csv")     
df = df.drop(columns="FILE_INFO").join(df.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x.replace("'","\""))).apply(pd.Series))` and got this error `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series`.

Comment: odd - your CSV contains exactly what you pasted?  pandas version? `pd.__version__`

Comment: yes it in my csv. that's the problem. pandas 1.21 version

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(f).rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
print(df.dtypes)
` what do you get from that?